# A question about TBB/C++ code

Tags: c++, tbb

I am reading The thread building block book. I do not understand this piece of code:

```
            FibTask& a=*new(allocate_child()) FibTask(n-1,&x);
FibTask& b=*new(allocate_child()) FibTask(n-2,&y);
```

What do these directive mean? class object reference and new work together? Thanks for explanation.

The following code is the defination of this class FibTask.

```
class FibTask: public task

{
public:

 const long n;
    long* const sum;
 FibTask(long n_,long* sum_):n(n_),sum(sum_)
 {}
 task* execute()
 {
  if(n<CutOff)
  {
   *sum=SFib(n);
  }
  else
  {
   long x,y;

   FibTask& a=*new(allocate_child()) FibTask(n-1,&x);
   FibTask& b=*new(allocate_child()) FibTask(n-2,&y);
   set_ref_count(3);
   spawn(b);
   spawn_and_wait_for_all(a);
   *sum=x+y;
  }
  return 0;

 }
};
```

Comment: Just nitpicking...it's called "Threading building blocks"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
new(pointer) Type(arguments);
```

This syntax is called [**placement new**](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10), which assumes the location `pointer` is already allocated, then the constructor of `Type` is simply called on that location, and return a `Type*` value.

Then this `Type*` is dereferenced to give a `Type&`.

Placement new is used when you want to use a custom allocation algorithm, as demonstrated in the code you're reading (`allocate_child()`).

Comment: Specifically for TBB task-based programming, they've mentioned it as: `Allocate space for the task. This is done by a special “overloaded new”`. As given in the TBB tutorial pdf Section 11.3.

Answer (score 4):

The code

```
   FibTask& a=*new(allocate_child()) FibTask(n-1,&x);
   FibTask& b=*new(allocate_child()) FibTask(n-2,&y);
```

creates two sub-task of the this task and set this task as the successor of the created task. The space used to allocate these task is managed by the this task when thsi->allocate_child() is used as placement. The advantage is that these sub-task are owned by the this task and released when the current task is released automatically. Note that this can be done because the current task will out life its subtask as it depends on them.

This could also be written as

```
   FibTask* a=new(allocate_child()) FibTask(n-1,&x);
   FibTask* b=new(allocate_child()) FibTask(n-2,&y);
   set_ref_count(3);
   spawn(*b);
   spawn_and_wait_for_all(*a);
```

The use of references instead of pointers force people that will maintain this code to don't think that the pointers must be deleted, Well this is the explanation I have found.

Comment: I think using pointers and leaving an obvious (and copious) comment would have been better practice. It's not obvious that the destructors (as opposed to delete) don't need to be called.

Comment: @Neil Yes you are right. The code is unusual and a little bit hard to read.

Comment: It's very confusing. `this->allocate_child()` (where `this` is a `tbb::task*`) returns a `internal::allocate_child_proxy&` which is what ultimately what gets used for the placement-new expression. Also in `tbb::task` is `static internal::allocate_root_proxy allocate_root()` which works similarly but is `static`. It baffles me that this weirdness wasn't hidden. It could have been `FibTask& a = this->make_child_task<FibTask>(n-1, &x);` for example, or `FibTask& a = task::make_root_task<FibTask>(n, &sum);`. One possible reason is that tbb predates C++11's perfect forwarding.

Comment: I'm tempted to just write free functions for those: `template <typename Task, typename... Args> Task& make_child_task(tbb::task& parent, Args&&... args) { return *new (parent.allocate_child()) Task(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }` and `template <typename Task, typename... Args> Task& make_root_task(Args&&... args) { return *new (tbb::task::allocate_root()) Task(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }`.